# QueryBuilder genera Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

¿Como estan?

Estoy desarrollando un programa con symfony 3.4 , xampp y mariadb 10. Debo hacer una consulta con una subconsulta anidada:
Debo recorrer una tabla SOLICITUD buscando si no existe una PERSONA determinada que busco con su dni con una solicitud existente. Lo he resuelto usando el siguiente codigo:

```
 $subconsulta = 'SELECT p.id FROM ComensalesBundle:Persona p where p.dni =  ' . $Dni ;
$consulta = 'SELECT s FROM ComensalesBundle:Solicitud s where s.persona = (' .$subconsulta. ')';
```

No logro que me funcione usando el QueryBuilder de Doctrine, uso el siguiente code:

```
$db = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $db->createQueryBuilder();
    $subqb = $qb;
    //escribo la subconsulta
    $subqb =  $subqb->select('p.id')
            ->from('ComensalesBundle:Persona','p')
            ->where('p.dni = ' . $Dni)
            ->getDQL()

            ;
    //$resultado = $subqb->getResult();
    //var_dump($subqb);
    //escribo la consuta
    $q = $qb->select('s')
       ->from('ComensalesBundle:Solicitud','s')
       ->where('s.persona = ' . $subqb)
       ->getQuery()
            ;

    $resultado = $q->getResult();
```

Me genera el siguiente error:**[Syntax Error] line 0, col 89: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'**
Supongo que estoy armando mal la consulta pero despues de buscar en foros no logro darle una solución. Soy un usuario con poca experiencia y estoy dentro de todo progresando en lo que es programación web, cualquier aporte sera bienvenido.
Muchas gracias
Saludos

Comment: Another tip: Use a `JOIN` instead of a subquery.

Comment: @ccKep He is already registered there! Funny people...

Comment: @gp_sflover I don't understand what you mean by that, your StackExchange account is shared among those sites (so you and I are 'registered' there aswell).

Comment: muchas gracias por las retroalimentaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar usar NativeQuery

```
$sql1 = "select id from persona where p.dni =  ?";
$sql2 = "select * from solicitud where persona_id = " . $sql1;

$conn = $em->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, '4325xxxx');
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Desde el controlador (el cual no recomiendo)

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

Si estas usando un Repository

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
```

Slds

Comment: Muchas gracias por la retroalimentación. Lo pude resolver haciendo la subconsulta como me la muestras y la consulta con sqlbuider.